# Why do browser Javascript libraries pass the window object as an argument?

Tags: javascript

While looking at various JavaScript libraries, I have noticed a relatively common practice of passing either the `window` or the `document` object as part of the arguments given to the library initialization function.

Examples:

- [DOM4](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom4/1.0.1/dom4.max.js)
- [ContentLoaded](https://github.com/dperini/ContentLoaded/blob/master/src/contentloaded.js)
- [EasyXDM](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easyXDM/2.4.17.1/easyXDM.js)
- [fingerprintjs](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fingerprintjs/v0.5.1/fingerprint.js)

While I understand very well why that would be done for libraries that are designed to run on non-browser environments, I do not know why that is done for libraries that seem designed only for client browser environments. (Such as all the examples given above).

Comment: just because they are meant to be only used in browsers doesn't mean that they will (users are stupid)

Comment: @DanD. That should be an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also helps to speed up the library as `window` or `document` is now locally bound. And this also ensures that if latter the user, replaces the `window` object with say: `window = "Help, I'm trapped in a window overwriting assignment statement.";`; the library continues to work.

Comment: Also, it helps JS code minifiers in their work, as they can change the parameter name inside the function.